# TF2 Strange Counter Reset

Tags: team-fortress-2

I was wondering if I buy a strange killstreak weapon from the Community Market, will it reset the kill counter it already has on it, to 0?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, it will. This applies to any Strange weapon or cosmetic item, and to Steam Community Market purchases, regular trades, and gift trades (i.e. [Gift Wrapping](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Gift_Wrap) the Strange item before sending it to the recipient).

The notes on the wiki [say](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Strange#Notes) that simply *listing* a Strange item on the market will reset its kill counter to 0. I haven't sold anything on the market before so I don't know if it's true, but this is something to keep in mind if you plan on selling.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, trading or gifting any Strange item will reset its counter (and any other Strange Counters fixed to it) to 0.

The only way to get that Australian weapon is to do the hard work yourself!